# Proof of A is orthogonal $\Leftrightarrow \|Ax\|=\|x\|$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, orthogonal-polynomials

I want to proof this property.

A is orthogonal $\Leftrightarrow \|Ax\| = \|x\|$

I tried to elaborate from this, but cannot see how to get any further:
$\|A\| \times \sqrt{<x,x>}$

I really appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your equivalence

$$
A \quad \text{orthogonal} \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad || Ax|| = ||x|| \quad \text{for all} \quad x \ .
$$

Said this, one implication is clear: if $A$ is orthogonal, then

$$
||Ax||^2 = (Ax)^t(Ax) = x^t(A^tA)x = x^tx = ||x||^2 \ , \quad \text{for all} \quad x \ .
$$

And, since on both sides you have positive numbers, you can delete both squares.

For the other implication, you can take advantage of the computations already done: $||Ax|| = ||x||$ is the same as $x^t(A^tA)x = x^tIx$. Of course, this wouldn't mean that, necessarily $A^tA = I$, if the equality was true just for *one* or *some* $x$: you can't just cancel $x$'s on both sides. But, if it's true *for all* $x$, then you can say more:

- First, for any matrix $B$, what's $e_i^tBe_j$? (Here $e_i^t = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)$: just one $1$ in the $i$th coordinate, and the rest are zeros.)
- Then you should try to prove this equality (probably you already know it):

$$
x^ty =\frac{1}{2} \left( ||x+y||^2 - ||x||^2 - ||y||^2  \right) \ .
$$

Answer (score 7):

Clues:

1. $\|x\|^2=x^tx$
2. A orthogonal: $A^tA=I$